# Java Web Start of JRE 1.6.0_13 is not working on XP for user who does not have Admin privileges

Tags: java, java-web-start

Here I need to upgrade my Java Web start from JRE 5x to 6x so that my application can work on Windows7 as JRE 5x Java Web start does not work on Windows7.

Java Web Start of JRE 1.6.0_13 is not working on XP for user who does not have Admin privileges. It works properly if user have admin privileges.

In JNLP:

Java Web Start of JRE 1.5.0_11 works fine and download the required JRE from my server irrespective user have admin privileges or not.

Error in Java Web Start Console while using JWS of JRE6x and user without having admin privileges on Windows XP:

> Java Web Start 1.6.0_13 Using JRE
>   version 1.6.0_13 Java HotSpot(TM)
>   Client VM User home directory =
>   C:\Documents and Settings\mc0054626
>
> Java Web Start Error:
>   
>   The application has requested a version of the JRE (version 1.6+) that
>
> currently is not locally installed.
>   Java Web Start is unable to
>   automatically download and install the
>   requested version. This JRE must be
>   installed manually.

Please suggest.

Comment: What is the exact nature of the failure? What error messages are generated/logged? Assume that we all lack Win7 and so require you to provide that information; edit it onto the end of your question please.

Comment: I am upgrading to JWS of JRE6x so that i can support Windows7 & it worked. But its not working on XP for users who does not have admin privileges. If i use JWS of JRE5x it works fine on Windows XP for users who does not have admin rivileges.    Java Web Start Error: The application has requested a version of the JRE (version 1.6+) that currently is not locally installed. Java Web Start is unable to automatically download and install the requested version. This JRE must be installed manually.

Comment: Looks like the Java Webstart application requires a newer Java 6 JRE version that 1.6.0_13 and therefore WebStart tries to download and install this JRE versions which fails because of the missing permissions. Install Java the most recent JRE (1.6.0_23) and/or review the jnlp file (which JRE version it wants) which causes this error.

Comment: Hi Robert, I will try with JRE(1.6.0_23), But if user have admin privileges then it works for same JWS and JNLP file. It does not expect any specific JRE. Like how admin privileges are impacting the required JRE thing.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but this may have something to do with the introduction of the [Java Deployment Toolkit](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/deployment_toolkit.xml) in Java 1.6.10.

Unfortunately I do not know if there is a way to make it work without Admin privileges.

On a side note, 1.6.10 through 1.6.19 include a rather serious [remote code exploit](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2010/Apr/119) and [privilege escalation bug](http://www.securiteam.com/securitynews/6R03L0U0KK.html) was found in 1.6.0-1.6.20.  Therefore, you should upgrade to 1.6.21 or newer.